# How to get a subdomain to point a different server than the main domain

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I have a site at say:

foo.com and I would like the subdomain blog.foo.com to point to fooblog.com

blog.foo.com -> fooblog.com

However, our DNS provider says that if we do an alias such as that, since the provider at fooblog.com does not recognize the name blog.foo.com. We asked if we could just point blog.foo.com at the IP address of fooblog.com and they say the same problem will occur.

Any advice? Due to our configuration we can't really put the blog on foo.com. We are willing to move our hosting and even our domain name hosting if necessary.

--

Yes, I am a n00b when it comes to DNS.

Answer (score 2):

Your DNS provider is right. Justing pointing a DNS record to a server isn't going to show the right website on that sub(domain). Some configuration on the webserver is needed for this to work. You can ask your webhosting provider to create an alias (in Apache: `ServerAlias`) for the subdomain. If they do that for you, your website would be visible on the subdomain too.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit of a hack but why not do a simple redirect. Something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)?

But to answer your question, as others have said, without some reconfiguration on fooblog.com just pointing the DNS will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create an alias from `blog.foo.com` and point it at `fooblog.com` -- I don't see why that would not work, unless the web server on the target is filtering by host-header values. And if that's the case, changing DNS providers would not fix it.